# null body issue with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

when i try to do an AJAX call to get some html text, i get a null body file. (Context is i am trying to do a hybrid application on Android and used weinre to check  what i have received from the AJAX call)

The AJAX call is within the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
     $("#generate").click(function(){  
    $.ajax ({  
        cache: false,
        url: "htmlpage1.html", 
        success: function(html) {
        console.log(html);
        $("#quote p").append(html);
        }
    });  
});
```

and the htmlpage1.html is the following

```
<body>  
This is page1

    <p><b>And this is some text which has been bolded</b></p>
    <p>And this is the link to page 2

</body>
```

did some research on stackoverflow and tried by luck with  the following 'magical' line to the ajax code, the problem is somehow fixed

```
 if(null==document.body){document.body = $('body')[0];}
```

what is the reason i get this issue in the first instance and how this problem is fixed by this code

if i dont use the magical code line but instead insert a dummy  tag in the html_page1 file, i manage to get the html file via AJAX (i.e. null body tag is fixed. )

Comment: `document.body` has nothing to do with your remote file. What does `console.log(html)` give you ?

Comment: What context is this running in - a local file, a domain ...?

Comment: thanks for your replies,

console.log(html) in weinre gives me Document (with a bunch of properties) in case i cant display the AJAXed html file, and in case the fiel can be displayed, console.log gives the entire html file.

the context is the local domain.

Comment: Is there anything in your code to prevent the default click action from occurring? I'm not sure how that would affect anything (or even if #generate is a link). You can also set the dataType parameter in $.ajax to 'html' and see if that helps, since the HTML you're returning doesn't specify that it's valid HTML jQuery might be confused.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to find the body tag before appending it, it might give you the content you need...   try playing with the selectors, I had a similar issue before.

```
$("#quote p").append($(html).find("body"));
```

Comment: apologies for the delayed reply. i restarted my system and the problem disappeared!!. i like the tip regarding the find("body") issue, in case i hit the problem next time i will try this